# How do you delete a file from an Azure Data Lake using the Python SDK?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-lake, data-lake

I'm using the azure-storage-file-datalake plugin for Python 3.8.  The SDK is described in great depth here --
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakedirectoryclient?view=azure-python, but no where is there a description of whether you can delete a file from the data lake, the SDK only describes deleting directories.  Is it possible to delete a file?

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, I tried this ...

```
file = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string(
                my_connection_string, 
                file_system_name=filesystem, 
                file_path=path
            )
            file.delete_file()
```

but the last line results in this error

```
TypeError('element indices must be integers')
```

Comment: Hello, I want to check if you have solved the issue or not. If it's solved, could you please accept the answer below? And if you still have more issues, please let me know:). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

First, I'm installing the latest python sdk for adls gen2. Using the command below:

```
pip install azure-storage-file-datalake==12.1.1
```

Here is my test code:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient

conn_str="xxxx"
filesystem="aaa"
file_path="foo2.txt" #if the file is in a directory, like in directory test1, you should specify the path as "test1/foo2.txt"

fileClient = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str=conn_str,
    file_system_name=filesystem,
    file_path=file_path
)

fileClient.delete_file()

print("**completed**")
```

And the test result:

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

If you want to delete a file, you should take a look at [DataLakeFileClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakefileclient?view=azure-python). In this class, it has a `delete_file` method. Please take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakefileclient?view=azure-python#delete-file---kwargs-) for its usage.

**Or** when you use [DataLakeDirectoryClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakedirectoryclient?view=azure-python), you can get the file client by using `get_file_client()` method of `DataLakeDirectoryClient` instance, then call the `delete_file()` method.

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: Hi, I gave this a go, but it results in a cryptic "TypeError('element indices must be integers')" error.  I included the code as an edit to my question.

Comment: @Dave  Just to confirm, are you using Azure Data Lake Gen2?

Comment: Hi, Yes it is.  Also the plugin version is 12.0.2 if that matters.

Comment: @Dave, it doesn't matter if the version is 12.0.2 or 12.1.1. Please try the code, and let me know any issues:)

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  The "delete_file" call throws the exception "azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Accepted'" but when I check on the data lake the file is removed, so I guess it worked?  Idk, I feel like there should be a cleaner solution that doesn't throw an exception at all and still deletes the file.  But I'm not all that familiar with this SDK.

Comment: @Dave, that's really weird since it's no such error at my side. I suggest that you can create a new ADLS Gen2 account, then give it a try. Maybe you have some other settings in this account.

Comment: @ Ivan, Can you please tell me how to get connection string for ADLS Gen2 ?